# Server returns 404 on assets for PWA with vue

Tags: github, vue.js, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I run NPM build on the PWA boilerplate I am using.

Folder structure on server is as follows:

my-project ->
  static,
  index.html,
  service-worker

I have then hosted on server and the Manifest and assets are returning a 404.

The project is currently here.

https://evilernie44.github.io/my-project/

Any help is much appreciated.

Changing routes on the manifest and two different servers

I want to get a boiler-plate hosted as a starting point for my PWA

Answer (score 0):

Your script tags point to the wrong path.
Take this tag for example:

```html
<script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.98f21a65b373eaa50022.js></script>
```

The browser resolves it to https://evilernie44.github.io/static/js/app.98f21a65b373eaa50022.js, which does not exist.
The correct path should be `./static/js/app.98f21a65b373eaa50022.js`. The extra dot instructs the browser to build the full url **relative to the current path**.

Alternatively, you can specify an **absolute path**, such as `/my-project/static/js/app.98f21a65b373eaa50022.js` which points to the correct location.

In conclusion, any of the following 2 script tags would work:

```html
<script type=text/javascript src=./static/js/app.98f21a65b373eaa50022.js></script>
```

```html
<script type=text/javascript src=/my-project/static/js/app.98f21a65b373eaa50022.js></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, ill try that now. Im really confused as to why  when you build the app this is not done automatically. Am I just expecting too much>?#

Comment: Perhaps vue is not aware of github hosting your app on a subdirectory

Comment: Maybe, I have tried this suggestion. Just to clarify you mean amend the script at the bottom of the index.html? Also, would I need to rebuild it and then redeploy or should I be able to just change the script tag?

Comment: Will the rest of the paths also need to be amended also manifest.json ect?

Comment: Yes, all the paths will have to be changed in index.html. I'm not sure how github pages work, but it'll probably autoupdate when you commit and push

Answer (score 0):

By default Vue CLI assumes you are running the application as root, so it will try to load the files from '/'.

When deploying to production, or in a subfolder, you need to set the `publicPath` in `vue.config.js`

https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath